# Program that has proper layout on all device android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently writing a remote control program to control a robot on all android devices.
I am trying to display the layout to fill the screen fully on different sizes. My first try was on a samsung 10.1' tablet and it was working well but when I port it to smaller devices like 4.3' the layout goes wrong. I am thinking of creating several layouts to match with different screen sizes but how do I check which layout to set according to screen sizes?
I have tried getwidth and getheight but it only works after you have set the layout.
Please give me a short sample code if possible as I am very new to this.

If there are any other better ways please advice me on it.

Please note that I am using API level 8, android 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Basically, you create layout for various screen, each with same name. They are put in different folders (each named according to factors like- landscape, portrait, screen density and screen size). OS will decide on it's own about which layout to use.

Comment: If I use this, setContentView(R.layout.main);
My folder name is layout and the xml is called main.
Do you mean that I create different layout for different screen sizes called "main.xml" but put it in folders named "layoutlarge" or "layoutsmall"? If so do I have to edit the setContentView?

Comment: yes,kind of. naming convention is different, something like- "layout-xlarge". please refer the links.

example-
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")

res/layout-small/my_layout.xml // layout for small screen size

res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size

res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size

res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml

similarly for drawables.

Comment: All right thanks. But just to make sure of the last thing as it is not mentioned in the link, for"setContentView(R.layout.main)" do i have to change the name of the folder and xml file? Or do i just use this as the standard one and android will do the changes for me?

Comment: From every layout (id, drawable, menu etc), Android creates an constant. It's that constant that is referred by R.layout.main. All layout with same name has same constant value. Basically, Android will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) is great article about that. But in overall, never expect the screen to be any static size. But if you're deciding to create layout for each size, you don't have to worry about choosing the best layout, android will do it for you if you provide multiple versions of same layout.

Comment: I am sorry but can you elaborate more? How do android choose which layout is the most appropriate one? What do I have to do for it to happen?

Comment: Assuming you're creating the layout using XML editor, there's choice to create layout for each screen density. It will create new XML file for each layout just like its done for bitmaps to support each screen density(for low density, medium density and high density) Android will change over them according to the density of screen.

Comment: The process Android uses for selecting the best layout (or any resource) is described here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to check the screen dimensions.  Just create your layouts, and Android will automatically pick the correct one for your screen size, orientation, API level, etc.  See here for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html